# Font conflict Futura and Palatino in the same document

Tags: fonts, installing, incompatibility

I need to use de Futura font as Sans Serif an Palatino as Serif font in my document.
Well, I have installed the Futura pack from Gaehrken (http://www.gaehrken.de/tex/index.html). However, when I use the Futura (see the minimal example and the figure) the Palatino writting gets pixelated.

Is there a way to fix it? Am I doing something wrong? Is there a better Futura pack?
Is the `pdfmapfile{bfu.map}` the correct way to call a map?

I am using Miktex 2.9 (64 bits) + TexnicCenter 2.0 Alpha 4.

Thanks !

Regards,

Will

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,twoside]{scrreprt}

\usepackage{scrhack}

\usepackage{geometry}
 \geometry{
 paperheight=240mm,
 paperwidth=170mm,
 inner=20mm,
 outer=15mm,
 top=20mm,
 bottom=15mm,
marginparwidth=0cm,
headheight=3mm,
 }

\usepackage{chngpage} % to easily change the margins of pages.

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%\usepackage{ucs} % Provides advanced support for using UTF-8 as the input encoding of LaTeX files.

\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc} % please do not change!
\usepackage[brazilian]{babel} % The multilingual package. 

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
%\usepackage{textcomp}

\usepackage{ae} % Fonte virtual para arquivo PDF com fonte CMR codificado como T1 (este pacote resolve problemas do mapeamento de fontes acentuadas do Computer Modern no documento PDF).

\usepackage{type1cm}
\usepackage{fix-cm}           % Permit Computer Modern fonts at arbitrary sizes.
\usepackage{fourier-orns}
\usepackage{lmodern}

%% Futura %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{bfutura}
     \pdfmapfile{bfu.map}

%% Palatino %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%    
\usepackage[sc]{mathpazo}
\usepackage{tgpagella}  

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document} 

\chapter{Test}

{\sffamily  This is a test with sffamily (Futura font).}\\
%
{This would be the normal text (Palatino font).}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First the real problem. When you say

```
\pdfmapfile{bfu.map}
```

you're telling `pdftex` to ignore the standard `pdftex.map` file and to load `bfu.map` *only*. Thus there will be no entry for the Palatino clone used by `mathpazo` and bitmap fonts will be generated.

Use

```
\pdfmapfile{=bfu.map}
```

instead.

Your document loads many font packages which are useless or even dangerous.

Remove the calls to `ae` (which is obsolete, by the way), `type1cm`, `fix-cm`, `lmodern`.

With `tgpagella` you're overriding the text font loaded by `mathpazo`, which might be a choice in order to use `mathpazo` just for the math fonts.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt answer and the tips concerning the typography. It is working perfectly now. Yes, I am using `mathpazo` only for the math fonts.